# Puppeteer inside VMWare VM not working over SSH in Ubuntu 22.04, works ok in desktop terminal

Tags: php, node.js, ssh, puppeteer, node-modules

System is Ubuntu 22.04, I've installed puppeteer using npm (no sudo). The machine is a virtual machine VMWare. My idea is being able to obtain the cookies of a page using puppeteer via crontab inside a php script, over SSH or by executing shell_exec("node test.js"). Nothing works and gives the same error.

I'm not an expert on either puppeteer or node, so please bear with me, I feel like I'm failing on something basic but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I have this very simple code, I try to execute it in ssh terminal using `node test.js`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            headless: true, 
            dumpio: {enabled: true, path: 'puppeteer-dump'}, 
            executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management']
        }
    );

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://example.com');

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I've tried all sorts of args, removing any or all of them, all combos, adding others; `using executablePath` or not (so it should use the chromium inside .cache folder). Using or not `--no-sandbox`. Nothing changes in the end.

The thing that is driving me nuts is that everything works perfectly if I execute `node test.js` inside the "graphical" terminal in Ubuntu's desktop. Headless or not. `executablePath` or not.

The error it gives using dumpio is the following:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:46767/devtools/browser/0f5486e9-f161-4433-9931-997c4da312a6

[190388:190388:0222/163811.523705:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
ERR: DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[190388:190388:0222/163811.523802:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
ERR: Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[190388:190388:0222/163811.523817:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[190388:190388:0222/163811.523862:ERROR:gl_display.cc(791)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[190388:190388:0222/163811.523880:ERROR:gl_display.cc(825)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[190388:190388:0222/163811.523890:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:96
    #error = new Errors_js_1.ProtocolError();
             ^

ProtocolError: Runtime.callFunctionOn timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.
    at <instance_members_initializer> (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:96:14)
    at new Callback (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:100:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:22:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:80:26)
    at CdpCDPSession.send (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:66:33)
    at #evaluate (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/ExecutionContext.js:202:50)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/ExecutionContext.js:117:16)
    at async IsolatedWorld.evaluate (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/IsolatedWorld.js:124:16)
    at async CdpJSHandle.evaluate (/var/www/html/testnode/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/JSHandle.js:142:20)

Node.js v20.11.0
```

I guess it is something related to access to the GPU? I have no idea since I've found nothing about this problem. Maybe is it how it is? You can't access use this over ssh? It doesn't work even using for example `shell_exec` inside PHP.